# Batch create text files, each new file with different text pulled from two different text files

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to create multiple text files from  2 template text file; however, in each newly generated file there should be added a new line of text pulled from excel row.

for example:

template1 text file content

```
Line1
Line2

Line 3
```

template2 text file content

```
Line4

Line5
```

And Excel file has several rows, each with different text, e.g.

```
Row1text
Row2text
Row3text
```

So what I need to do is pull from Excel rows the text and add it to the newly generated text file, based on text template file,

so the result would be like this

GeneratedText1.txt

```
Line1
Line2

Line 3

Row1text

Line4

Line5
```

GeneratedText2.txt

```
Line1
Line2

Line 3

Row2text

Line4

Line5
```

GeneratedText3.txt

```
Line1
Line2

Line 3

Row3text

Line4

Line5
```

As many as there are rows in excel, so many the text files should be generated. The names of the new files should be also predefined somewhere. What's the best way to do it? Some command line would help?

Here is what I have managed so far:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set i=1
for /f %%l in (input.cvs) do (
  >GeneratedText!i!.txt type template1.txt
  >>GeneratedText!i!.txt echo %%l
  set /a i+=1
)

endlocal
```

Comment: You say the text files are templates, so assume no variable data present in them. Where are the names of the output files derived? Are they based on data content in Excel?

Comment: Please edit your original post and include the code in your comment.  use four spaces before each line to format as code. Thanks

Comment: Yes, the values in the template are standard values. right now, I haven't thought about the name (It's will be my second task naming the each txt file separately) (Output - I am able to copy the content of the template1 plus the data from the excel file into multiple text files, but I am stuck as to how to append the template2 information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should create files with the two template files and a line from the excel.txt file between them, as you have shown.

The filenames are derived from the excel line and should not contain poison characters.

This is untested:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (excelfile.txt) do (
   type "template1.txt" >"%%a.txt"
      >>"%%a.txt" echo(
      >>"%%a.txt" echo(%%a
      >>"%%a.txt" echo(
   type "template2.txt" >>"%%a.txt"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will merge two text template files with data from your excel sheet. You need to determine the cell range, and how to name your output files.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Create_Text_Files()
Dim strLineIn   As String
Dim lRow        As Long

    ' Determine Excel Range (Rows & Colums!!
    For lRow = 2 To 5          '<<< Set your Range!!
        Close #1    ' Just in case left open during testing
        Close #2
        Close #3
        Open "C:\temp\TemplateFile1.txt" For Input As #1
        Open "C:\temp\TemplateFile2.txt" For Input As #2
        'Determine how to name your output files.
        Open "C:\temp\TemplateOut" & lRow & ".txt" For Output As #3         ' Set Output File Name

        'Write out TemplateFile1.txt
        Do While Not EOF(1)         ' Loop until end of file
            Line Input #1, strLineIn
            If EOF(1) Then Exit Do      ' Avoid blank line
            Print #3, strLineIn
        Loop
        Close #1

        'Get your Excel data and write out
        Print #3, Cells(lRow, 1)            ' Change if multi column
        'Write out TemplateFile2.txt
        Do While Not EOF(2)         ' Loop until end of file
            Line Input #2, strLineIn
            If EOF(2) Then Exit Do      ' Avoid blank line
            Print #3, strLineIn
       Loop
       Close #2
       Close #3
    Next lRow
End Sub
```